# Sharepoint Loading Slowly Internally But Not Externally

Tags: windows, dns

Everything seems to load very quickly outside the office but internally, Sharepoint seems to take a strangely long time to load up a page.

```
Server: Windows SBS 2011 Standard (.2 internal IP)
Router: Linksys Wireless (.1 internal IP)

PC: Windows 7
PC IPConfig: 

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MyComputer
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : myserver.local

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-26-9E-8C-31-92
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : myserver.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.102(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, February 29, 2012 8:43:49 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, March 08, 2012 9:25:50 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 


   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{     }:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: What is the specific programming question here?

Comment: Search the ULS trace for the requests from outside and inside ones and then compare them. That should give a clue.